# Search ruby gems scoped by source URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, rubygems

I'm looking for a way to obtain a list of all the gems in a private source website, using a syntax like this (fake url provided for security reasons):

```
gem search -r --source https://www.myexample.com/gems-repo/
```

just shows a list of all the gems from all the sources I have added to my gems config (thus a really big list, https://rubygems.org/ alone bears hundreds), the source switch in the command above doesn't seem to be used at all.
Is there a way to accomplish this task?
Thank you.

Comment: This might be possible if you use a private gem hosting service or tool that exposes an API. You'll have to dig deeper and see if `search` is like `apt` or `yum` in that it searches all repos or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a private gem hosting setup by me using apache's webdav features, but I don't have specific apis, I tried to dig more into gem search, but it looks like is not comparable to apt or similar tools. Anyway I think that, if digging more doesn't give results, I could use the listing of the webdav folder as a workaround.